# Python Pandas Merge Dataframe to get Unique Values Only

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I am new to using Pandas, and I want to merge two dataframes so that I get only the unique values from the first dataframe. I included an example below:

```
df1 = ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Carrot', 'Squash', 'Watermelon']
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df1)

df2 = ['Apple', 'Cucumber', 'Raddish', 'Watermelon']
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df2)

Result desired:
df3 = ['Banana', 'Carrot', 'Squash']
```

I've tried merging the two using "outer" and dropping duplicates, but that gives me all unique values across both data frames. How do I get just the unique values for df1? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you use `set` `difference` ?

Comment: `set(df1).difference(df2)`

Comment: Is there a way to check this and ignore case sensitive? ie if df1 contains 'Apple' and df2 contains 'apple', can I still use this and ignore the casing and consider those the same?

Answer (score 2):

This will give you desired answer

```py
ans = concat([df2, df1, df2]).drop_duplicates(keep=False)

''' 
Answer will be of type DataFrame you can later use 
ans[0].tolist() to get the required list of values
'''
```

This is how you calculate difference using pandas

#### Edit: Preprocessing to remove case sensitivity

```py
df1 = ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Carrot', 'Squash', 'Watermelon']
df1 = DataFrame(df1)

df2 = ['Apple', 'Cucumber', 'Raddish', 'Watermelon']
df2 = DataFrame(df2)

# Result desired:
# df3 = ['Banana', 'Carrot', 'Squash']

df1[0] = df1[0].str.lower()
df1[0] = df1[0].str.strip()

df2[0] = df2[0].str.lower()
df2[0] = df2[0].str.strip()

answer_df = concat([df2, df1, df2]).drop_duplicates(keep=False)

print(answer_df[0].tolist())
# output:
# ['banana', 'carrot', 'squash']
```

Comment: This one is not case sensitive. You need to preprocess in order to remove case sensitivity. Answer provided by @Jason Cook show a way to make all str values in column to upper and remove extra blank spaces. I will edit my code so you can follow.

also if this helps consider accepting the answer

Comment: Hey, If the answer helps consider accepting it

Answer (score 1):

Using merge:

```py
# since how='left', indicator will either be 'both' or 'left_only' 
result = df1.merge(df2, how='left', indicator=True)

# keep values that were in left dataframe only
result = result[result['_merge']=='left_only']

# result as list
result[0].tolist()

# or result as dataframe (drop extra _merge column that was created)
# result = result.drop(columns='_merge')
```

If you are concerned with case sensitivity and basic data cleansing you can use the string methods for objects before merging:

```py
df1[0] = df1[0].str.upper()
df1]0] = df1[0].str.strip()
```